# JDBC update a single field from object

Tags: sql, jdbc, sql-update

I am doing a jdbc update to a table from an object.  The object has several attributes and I only want to update my table with the objects that have a value.  The problem is that the update statement below will wipe all omitted values if they are not in the object.

For example:

```
 String statementStr = "update users " 
                         + "set firstName = ?, lastName = ?, email = ?, birthday = ?, "
                         + "gender = ?"
                         + "where id = ?;";
```

How can I modify this statement to only update the populated value from my object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctlly, then you can use `ISNULL()` to update the field with non nullable poperties only, otherwise leave the field without update it:

```
UPDATE users 
SET firstName = ISNULL(@nameParam, firstName), 
    lastName = ISNULL(@lastNameParam, lastName), 
    email = ISNULL(@emailParam, email),
    ...
WHERE id = ?;
```

Comment: can I substitute ? for the @param value?  I'm using prepared statements like:  prep.setString(2, user.getFirstName()) and I'm not sure how I can substitute the PS with your example.  Your example is exactly what i want to do!

Comment: You can substitute the `?` in the `WHERE` as well, but I leaved it for you to fill it with the condition you want. As it is different from the other `?` that were in the `SET` clause.

Comment: @Atma Yes, substitute with question marks. and depending on your rdbms flavour, use COALESCE rather than ISNULL: `String statementStr = "update users SET firstName = COALESCE(?, firstName), lastName = COALESCE(?, lastName),... WHERE id = ?"`